# How do you boot Debian? (What is an .iso file)

Tags: debian, laptop

I have downloaded Debian 5.0 and i have no clue how to install it on my other old laptop, what do i do?

What do I do with the .iso file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An ISO file is a raw CD/DVD disk image.

On Linux you would be able to burn it with `cdrecord` or `cdrdao`, and if you are on Windows 7 I believe it has got the iso to disk ability. For other Windows versions you'll have to google for an ISO recorder such as [Infra Recorder](http://infrarecorder.org/) or [ISO Recorder](http://isorecorder.alexfeinman.com/isorecorder.htm) or [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/). On Mac OS X, use Apple's Disk Utility. The Ubuntu website [has detailed instructions for all operating systems](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto)

So you need to burn the ISO file onto the disk and not just copy the file there or extract its contents... A common mistake (often done by WinRar users) is to extract the image's contents as if it was a plain archive.

To boot from the CD you will also need to have the "boot order" configured in BIOS. On recent systems, there's a key (often <kbd>F8</kbd>) you can press for an one-time menu; with older ones, you will have to go inside the BIOS configuration screen. Either way, configure it to try "CD/DVD" before "HD". (Not all drives are able to boot from DVDs)

And since you said it's an "old laptop", chances are it will be too slow for the full installation (with X11 GUI and all sorts of services). But it being Linux, you will still be able to use the command-line to learn `bash` and uninstall unused packages.

Comment: Thanks, I have never got that before: lol `-v`

Comment: You _cannot_ burn CDs with `dd`.